# refactoring to an attached property

Tags: wpf, xaml, attached-properties

I am trying to change the code below from being an event setter to an attached property (just so I can clean up the code behind). I get an error in the setter saying the value cannot be null, but I don't see why yet.

Forgetting for a second whether this is a good idea or not, can someone help me get the attached property right?

Cheers,
Berryl

## EventSetter (works but with code behind as shown)

```
    <!-- SINGLE CLICK EDITING -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
    </Style>

private void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var cell = sender as DataGridCell;
    cell.Activate();
}
```

## Property setter (error)

```
<!-- SINGLE CLICK EDITING -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="begavior:DataGridCellProperties.SingleClickToEdit" Value="True"/>
</Style>

public class DataGridCellProperties
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SingleClickToEditProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SingleClickToEditProperty",
                                            typeof(bool), typeof(DataGridCellProperties),
                                            new PropertyMetadata(false, OnSingleClickToEditPropertyChanged));

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForChildren(IncludeDescendants = false)]
    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(DataGridCell))]
    public static bool GetSingleClickToEdit(DataGridCell obj) { return (bool)obj.GetValue(SingleClickToEditProperty); }

    public static void SetSingleClickToEdit(DataGridCell obj, bool value) { obj.SetValue(SingleClickToEditProperty, value); }

    private static void OnSingleClickToEditPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var sender = obj as UIElement;
        if (sender == null) return;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            sender.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown_EditCell;
        }
        else
        {
            sender.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown_EditCell;
        }
    }

    private static void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown_EditCell(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var cell = sender as DataGridCell;
        cell.Activate();
    }
}
```

Comment: put a breakpoint at `cell.Activate();` and is the `cell` null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"SingleClickToEditProperty" in your d-prop registration should be "SingleClickToEdit".